# exporting svg element to svg file end with a cut image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

So I have a div in position relative. I'm supposed to add manually text to the div. At the end I'm supposed to extract svg file of that text.
So in order to add text I use svg.js the following way:

```
<div style=position: relative; height: 576px; width: 621px>
// dx draggable is an outer library component for dragging element
    <dx-draggable style position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 100px>
    
    <div id=object-0>
    // THE SVG.JS TEXT ELEMENT GOES HERE
    </div>
    
    </dx-draggable>
    
</div>
```

Then I position the text the following way:

```
    const draw = SVG().addTo(`#object-${idx}`).size(200, 200);

    const text = draw.text(o.text);
    text.transform({
      rotate: 45,
    });
    text.move(0, 0).font({fill: '#f06', family: 'Assistant', fontSize: o.fontSize});
    
    I position the text on x:300, y:100
```

The element's width is about 58px and 20px height

Then I export it in the following way to an svg file:

```
 let svgContent = document.getElementById('object-0').innerHTML;
 let blob = new Blob([svgContent]);
 this.fileSaverService.save(blob, 'filename.svg');

    I attached 2 images: the one represents the text I see in DOM. The second one represents the image as I see it in Chrom.
```

Both of them look bad: The one of the DOM shows the text is cut. The one in the browser shows completely different positions of the text. Why is that?

[image]

*It also happens without rotation. the image in the browser is positioned differently

Comment: I think we're going to need a [mcve] here i.e. something complete that we can actually run.

Comment: @RobertLongson I edited my question. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: 1. *HOW* do you position the text? 2. Can you paste the resulting SVG file somewhere?

Comment: @rishta I edited my question. Hope it's clearer. I'm trying to attach the svg element but it gets translated to the text itself and loses the svg definition. Do you know how can I attach it? also I tried attaching the svg but I got error for the format

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The browser shows exactly what you told him to show. It also seems like that your service to save svgs is creating a wrong svg. Just use canvas to create an image out of svg!

Comment: Investigate the positioning of that element with your browser's developer's tools (CTRL-SHIFT-I  usually (I as in Indians!)).